# Electron BrowserWindow return on close

Tags: javascript, electron

Is there a way to return values upon closing a BrowserWindow in electron?

At best I'd wish for a way to get the variables from the close event:

```
win.on('closed', function(variables received here) {
        console.log(variables + ' ' + received + ' ' + here);
        win = null;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to return values inside the close event. However, you can run a function before the window will close using `window.onbeforeunload`.

In this function you could get the information or data you need from your `BrowserWindow` instance and send a synchronous IPC message to your main process in order to get the variables you need.
If you send it synchronously, and then return `undefined` you will get the variables you need, and the `BrowserWindow` will still close, firing your `close` event as desired.

From their docs:

> Usually you would want to use the `beforeunload` handler to decide whether the window should be closed, which will also be called when the window is reloaded. In Electron, returning any value other than `undefined` would cancel the close.

Look at the [close event](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-close) for more information.